# Does transparency work with SSS in Unity's HDRP Lit shader?

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I am using Unity's HDRP Lit shader in Shader Graph (all are version 4.8.0-preview) on Unity 2018.3.0b12.

I am trying to use both transparency and subsurface scattering on the material. However, it appears that the visual appearance loses SSS when transparency is introduced.

Example: The cube on the left has transparency enabled, and has no visible SSS. The cube on the right has the same SSS settings as the left cube, however the right cube has no transparency enabled.
[image]

I need transparency to fade in the cube depending on its position, like this:
[image]

And here is my master node:
[image]

If anyone has an alternative solution that sidesteps this potential limitation, I am all ears. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, transparency doesn't work with SSS in Unity's HDRP Lit shader.

HOWEVER, you can set the surface type to "opaque" **and still keep alpha clipping enabled**. Enjoy.